# integration of trignometric function

Tags: integration

are these integrals same 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\sin x - \cos x|\,dx.$$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{1-\sin 2x}\,dx$$

If in the second integration I write  $(\sin x - \cos x)^2$, after removing root it will become $|\sin x - \cos x|$, but online calculator calculation  gives $\sqrt{32}$ as answer of first one and second integration answer is  $0$? Why? Please explain. I am new to integration.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: That may depend on the online calculator: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt(1-sin(2*x))+from+x%3D0+to+2*pi) gets it right. Blind trust is not a good idea with things found online.

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%20%5Cleft%7C%20sin%20x%20-%20cos%20x%5Cright%7Cdx                                                                                            https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%20%5Csqrt%7B1%20-%20sin%202x%20%7Ddx

Comment: @sumitgoyal Then change calculator...or take good care to input the correct format for the functions. Both integrals equal $\;4\sqrt2\;$ .

Comment: thanku sir :))  also check  2 link i provided above   , one answer is zero and other 4root 2

Comment: That calculator is of course wrong when it comes to $\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}$: if the integrand is strictly positive almost everywhere, the integral cannot be $0$. Loosely speaking, it seems due to having implemented the false identity $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. Wheter this is due to lazy design or it is a tradeoff for some symbolical advantage, it's hard to tell.

Comment: thanku sir  :)    i was so confused why my answer was wrong

Comment: @sumitgoyal And what lesson we did learn? Don't trust too much online (or whatever) symbolic calculators. Many suck, and others suck less but still sometimes they get high and output nonsenses. Better: think.

Comment: yes sir i got it will take care ,  can you tell me one more thing  how to break  | sin x - cos x  | in appropriate intervals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|\sin x - \cos x|=\sqrt{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}=\sqrt{\sin^2x+\cos^2x-2\sin x\cos x}=\sqrt{1-\sin 2x}$$

Comment: sir but in calculator it is showing different answers  , should i post link ?

Comment: Change calculator. This answer is correct. +1

Comment: @sumitgoyal use the Wolfram to check that

Comment: ok sir checking

Comment: yes checked 4 root 2 is answer of both

Comment: E.H.E  sir can you also tell me how to break | sin x - cos x|  into interval while solving plz

Comment: depend on  defintion of  absolute value which is $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: yes i know it  , iam  asking when we remove mod we have to take care in which interval its positive  , when i enounter  |x -3 | =0     i know i have to break limit at x =3    , but for | sinx - cos x| iam  not getting how to form intervals

Comment: solve the $(\sin x-\cos x)=0$